# Rotating an Image in Python

Tags: image, python-2.7, numpy, image-processing, scikit-image

`

```
import numpy 
import skimage.io
from skimage.transform import rotate
tr_1 = numpy.random.rand(5,300)
training_inputs = [numpy.reshape(tr_1[x,:], (3,10,10)) for x in range(len(tr_1))]
f = rotate(training_inputs[1], 90, resize=True)
```

The above code is giving an output of size (10,4,10). But image should be rotated and it's size should be of (3,10,10).

Any Suggestions and how to proceed with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`skimage.rotate` cannot rotate a 3 bands image. You have to rotate a band at a time.

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.io
from skimage.transform import rotate
tr_1 = numpy.random.rand(5,300)
training_inputs = [np.reshape(tr_1[x,:], (3,10,10)) for x in range(len(tr_1))]
f0 = rotate(training_inputs[1][0], 90, resize=True)
f1 = rotate(training_inputs[1][1], 90, resize=True)
f2 = rotate(training_inputs[1][2], 90, resize=True)
f = np.rollaxis(np.dstack((f0, f1, f2)), 2, 0)
```

the `shape` of `f` will be `(3, 10, 10)`